# Dax Formula for Calendar

Tags: sql-server, query, dax

I have been trying to make a new table and want to use the date of the existing data. Can anyone help me understanding what is wrong with this formula?

```
dDate = CALENDAR(DATE(YEAR(MIN(Ftransactions[Date])),1,1),DATE(YEAR(MAX(Ftransactions[Date])),12,31))
```

The error which keeps popping up after pressing enter is:

> An argument of function 'YEAR' has the wrong data type or the result is too large or too small. If the argument is expected to be a date, that date must be between January 1, 100 and December 31, 9999.

Comment: What does the argument for YEAR return by itself?  i.e. "MIN(Ftransactions[Date])".  Does it return a valid date, and is the date between that range?